# Validating model attributes, best practices

Tags: ios, swift, model, encapsulation

I would like to valide my model's attributes before instantiating it.

```
class Book {

    private var _title: String!

    var title: String {
        if title != "" {
            return _title
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously throws an error at `return nil`. I am using this as a graphic illustration of what I am trying to do.

I have tried working with failable initializers however it seems like the init method is the wrong place to apply attribute validation.

How is this achieved using best practices?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You cannot check `title != ""` because it will call `title` again, and will loop infinitely. Also, your `title` is a `not nil variable`, so, you cannot return nil.

Comment: @t4nhpt I want to know what the best practices are to validate model objects

Comment: What you want to validate? Example, do you want to check it nil then return empty?

Comment: Example: if an attempt is made to instantiate a Book with `title = ""` then the object should not be created. Or attempt to instantiate Dog with `legs > 4` should not be created. @t4nhpt

Answer (score 0):

This is not a best practice to validate a model object, but it can achieve your requirement in a simple way.

```
class Book {

   private var _title: String = ""

   var title: String {
       return _title
   }

   init?(title:String) {

       if title == "" {
           return nil
        } else {
            self._title = title
        }
    }
}
```

When create a `Book` object, it require to provide `title`. If `title` is empty, the object will not be created (nil).

Comment: notice in my question i specify `I have tried working with failable initializers however it seems like the init method is the wrong place to apply attribute validation. `

Comment: What do you want if an attribute is invalid?